# How can I change access modifiers of more than one method in one shot by using ReSharper?

Tags: .net, refactoring, resharper, access-modifiers, renaming

Is there a short-cut in ReSharper to change more than one method's access-modifiers from something to something else?

Let's say I will choose methods:

```
public void Method_1(){...}
private void Method_2(){...}
private void Method_3(){...}
public void Method_4(){...}
```

And by using ReSharper I will change the acess-modifiers of them to internal.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

No. Currently there's no way to batch-apply ReSharper fixes to a selection apart from Code Cleanup, but Code Cleanup doesn't support changing visibility.
The best thing you can do is to make use of ReSharper feature called [Find Code Issues](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Find_Code_Issues):

1. Select ReSharper > Inspect > Code Issues in Solution or Code Issues in Project.
   Alternatively, select a file or folder in Solution Explorer, right-click, and select Find Code Issues. You'll get the list of issues in the Inspection Results tool window.
2. Click "Filter issues" in the Inspection Results tool window.
3. Leave only the issue types that are related to member visibility, for example "Member can be made private", "Member or type can be made internal" etc.
4. Get back to the list of issues in Inspection Results, and fix highlighted visibility one-by-one by clicking Enter to open the editor in the code position where the issue is, Alt+Enter to fix, and Ctrl+Alt+V (Visual Studio keyboard scheme) to get back to the Inspection Results window.

This workaround is only applicable to methods that ReSharper says can be narrowed in visibility. For methods that it doesn't highlight this way, you can only use its context actions (actions marked with pencil icons) one by one in the code editor - provided that you know what you're doing, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Resharper. Why make a private method internal anyway? If you are making a private method internal there is nothing to refactor, right?